# How to add body while making GET call in Java

Tags: get, okhttp, http-get, spring-webclient

I am trying to get token from auth server, Auth server provided GET API which require following parameters in body i.e.  client id and client secret , grant_type.

I tried with springs resttemaplte, webclient from springboot as well as okhttp .
still i am not able to pass body with HTTP GET /token method.

i tried with okhttp but getting following error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: method GET must not have a request body.
```

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().build();

```
RequestBody body = new MultipartBody.Builder().setType(MultipartBody.FORM).addFormDataPart("grant_type", "client_credentials")
        .addFormDataPart("client_id", "9eb43929-1212-41e8-92bf-12313131").addFormDataPart("client_secret", "7RD7Q~1313131~HFBE2DoXR37zrcLCdpLnP")
        .addFormDataPart("resource", "eb63d611-525e-4a31-1212-0cb33f679599").build();
Request request = new Request.Builder().url("https://host/oauth2/token/").method("GET", body).build();
Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

OkHttp does not support GET requests with bodies. You'll need to either change which HTTP method you’re using, or use a different HTTP client.

Comment: I tried resttemplate and webclient from spring, any other client can help?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that a POST method won't work?  I don't know why any auth server would require a body using a GET method since that violates REST standard convention